# List all Names and Values of an Object

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way that I can print out all names and values of an `Object` where `Object` can be of any class?

**i.e.** If `Object` was `Person` and `Person` had a member variable `Integer age;` - **I need a method** that could receive an instance of `Object` (where the `Object` is `Person` in this case but could be any other type of object) and print out `age - 35` where `age` is the member variable `name` and `35` is its `value`.

Something like:

```
public Map<String, String> getNamesAndValues(Object object) {
  Map<String, String> namesAndValues = new HashMap<>();
  //Populate namesAndValues Map here using object in signature.
  return namesAndValues;
}
```

If variables are `private` or `protected` then it should check for `getters` as well.

Comment: You could do it using reflection. What have you tried?

Comment: In general, why will you have a list of Objects? Perhaps you may want to reconsider your implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a try, that use spring [`ReflectionUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html).
NB: this rely on the fact that "value" have a proper string representation and it's not recursive (i.e. 1-level depth)

```
package com.stackoverflow.so22075052;

import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class F {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // fill a list
        final List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(A.of(1));
        objects.add(B.of("2"));

        // introspect
        for (final Object object : objects) {
            ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(object.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doWith(final Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                    System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", field.getName(),  ReflectionUtils.getField(field, object));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    static class A {
        private int age;

        public static A of(final int age) {
            final A a = new A();
            a.age = age;
            return a;
        }
    }

    static class B {
        private String string;

        public static B of(final String string) {
            final B b = new B();
            b.string = string;
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
age - 1
string - 2
```

---

EDIT:

[BeanUtils#describe](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#describe%28java.lang.Object%29) and a `Map` might be another solution

Answer (score 3):

You could use Java reflection to analyze all fields of a given object and print them with their values. For more information, look at the reflection doc: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html

Comment: "Reflection" is the method, learn to read and use the Java API.

Comment: @ThreaT Generally, if you want a method, you should write one yourself and ask for help improving it/making it work.

Comment: +1. Introspection / Reflexion are the standard way to do this.

Comment: @ThreaT the are no ready-to-use method for that. At most, you can hope that `toString()` is well implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (Object object : list) {

            if(object instanceof Person) // Cross check that object contain Person object
            {
                Person person = (Person) object;

                System.out.println("Person age "+person.age());

            }

        }
```

Comment: Its just cross check,u can remove it.

Comment: @ThreaT if the object will be strickly of person class then u can remove the instanceof check otherwise you need to check it

Comment: u can only remove if(object instanceof Person) , other than that like type cast all that u have to do

Answer (score 0):

Each object should be responsible for representing itself when printed. Here is how you accomplish that:

```
class MyClass {
    int myValue;
    public MyClass(){myValue = 2}; // constructor
    public String toString() {
        return "value " + myValue;
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to print your class from this point on, simply say

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
System.out.println(mc);
```

Comment: @ThreaT No, only the ones you specifically need to print. If all you need is `age` and `name`, then every object that comes in must be guaranteed to have an `age` and a `name`. If you pass in a nameless bastard, your program throw an exception (and why shouldn't it?).

Comment: @ThreaT Misunderstood your question. Edited to answer your actual question. An generic method cannot possibly print the members of ANY object, because some of them could be `private`. Each object is responsible for representing *itself*.

Comment: @ThreaT Again, objects are responsible for representing *themselves*. You can keep saying you need a generic method all day, but the truth is, you'll never be able to write a method that can process all of the members of any object in the world. What you seek is *One `toString()` to rule them all, One `toString()` to find them, One `toString()` to bring them all and in the darkness bind them*. If such a toString existed, wouldn't EVERYONE be using it to represent their objects by default, rather than a useless hashcode + gibberish?

Answer (score 0):

I have created some methods a while ago to accomplish what you want/need:

```
public final class MyObjectUtils {

    private static List<Field> getAllFields(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz.equals(Object.class)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
        fields.addAll(getAllFields(clazz.getSuperclass()));
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields()));
        return fields;
    }

    private static List<Field> getModifiableFields(Class<?> clazz) {
        List<Field> fields = getAllFields(clazz);
        List<Field> realFields = new ArrayList<Field>();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (!(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) || java.lang.reflect.Modifier
                    .isFinal(field.getModifiers()))) {
                realFields.add(field);
            }
        }
        return realFields;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> getFieldsAndData(Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
        List<Field> fields = getModifiableFields(object.getClass());
        Map<String, Object> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (!field.isAccessible()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
            values.put(field.getName(), field.get(object));
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

It is not a straight answer, but you can adapt it to your needs.